# How to move StackLayout with long Press gesture?

Tags: android, animation, vue.js, drag-and-drop, nativescript-vue

I would like to move a StackLayout using the long press gesture. My idea is to move a StackLayout by changing the position of the object. The result I want to get is that after a long press of a label I can move it elsewhere on a StackLayout.

```
<StackLayout orientation="horizontal" class="items">
  <StackLayout orientation="horizontal" class="item" @longPress="itemPress()">
  </StackLayout> 
</StackLayout>
```

script:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {

    };
  },

 methods: {
   itemPress(){
     alert("longpress");
     //stuff...
   },
 }
```

Comment: Okay, but you're using `pan` and not `longPress`, so not sure what your code has to do with this or even what your issue is

Comment: I just edit my question

Comment: you would also want to use `@longPress="itemPress"`not `@longPress="itemPress()"`. though this may not solve the issue.

Comment: Nope, function work with @longPress="itemPress" and @longPress="itemPress()"